# Mudar cor da Celula

Tags: c#

Preciso alterar a cor da celula:

estou fazendo da seguinte maneira

```
 dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["nomeDaColuna"].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

porem eu não posso ficar passado o rowIndex eu teria que passar o "nome da linha"

Comment: Linhas não têm nomes. Por que você precisa que seja dessa forma? Tenho quase certeza que você não precisa de uma coisa que não existe.

Comment: Acredito que a melhor forma de vc fazer isso seria verificar o valor de um campo da sua linha e de acordo com o valor do campo setar sua cor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Você poderia explicar o que você quer fazer e qual o resultado que quer alcançar?
2. O que você quer dizer com "nome da linha" e por que tem que ser o "nome da linha"?

Assim, não existem nomes para as linhas dos *grids* em *DataGridView* até onde eu sei, mas você pode criar um dicionário para isso, o que vai dar um tanto de trabalho, por isso, acho melhor pensar o que você quer conseguir no fim antes e planejar um pouco.

```
dataGridView.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = "NomeDaLinha1";
dataGridView.Rows["NomeDaLinha1"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Seria algo assim, mas você teria que especificar os nomes de cada linha.

> Atenção: o código acima não foi testado.

Comment: É uma limitação do site que as vezes é um pouco incomoda mesmo. De qualquer forma, sinalizei seu post como comentário, sugiro que faça o mesmo, assim um moderador irá mover para os comentários.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Infelizmente as respostas não são movidas para comentários, mesmo que esteja escrito ali na hora de sinalizar.

Comment: @jbueno por mim então, deixaria como resposta, já que é uma tentativa de responder a pergunta, apesar desta faltar as informações citadas.

Comment: Como é que eu faço pra sinalizar como comentário?

Comment: Eu votei pra remover, mas acho que se manter apenas a parte que é tentativa de "resposta" ela SERÁ totalmente valida.